# How to add keys to data that is used to display pie chart in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array called countArray which simply just consists of numbers. I also have a parallel array called descArray which is essentially the keys to those values (the numbers in the countArray). In D3, I draw my pie chart using the values in countArray.

```
var vis = d3.select(divId).append("svg:svg").data([countArray]).attr("width",                 w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
```

When I hover over an arc in the pie chart and `console.log(d)`, I would see that the value and the key for the specific arc is the same. I want to know a way to append the key data from my `descArray` onto `d`.

```
            arcs.append("svg:path")
             .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                console.log(d);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I figured it out.

```
 var vis = d3.select(divId).append("svg:svg").data([descArray]).attr("width",                 w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
```

the values were actually binded elsewhere.